# Following windows

Tags: unity, compiz

I have installed WhatPulse on my Ubuntu 12.04. I would like the WhatPulse window(s) to follow me onto whatever workspace I go to (the windows are already always on top).
If it may help, I already have compizconfig installed and I have desktop cube set "on".

Thanks, mjchopperboy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you right click on the window top bar select "Always on visible workspace".

[image]

Now the window will be displayed in every workspace, as seen here:

[image]